# Erro ao consultar informações DB SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou utilizando a classe **sqliteopenhelper** do android para conexão com o banco de dados, o nosso método salvar(), está funcionando perfeitamente, mas nosso método buscar(), onde meu cursor lista todas as cidade cadastradas, não está encontrando a tabela, trazendo o seguinte erro no logcat: `no such table cidade.`

Abaixo segue nossa classe cidade onde é para exibir nossa lista de cidades e tb segue nossa CidadeDataSource onde encontra-se todos metodos de manipulação do banco.

O erro acontece no **onstart** na CidadeActivity, que chama o me metodo `buscar()` da minha `CidadeDataSource`:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Entramos no OnStart");
    this.popularLista((ArrayList<Cidade>)ds.buscar());

}
```

### Método buscar

```
public  List<Cidade> buscar(){

    String[] colunas = new String [] {"_id", "nome", "estado"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("cidade", colunas, null, null, null, null, "nome ASC");

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Entramos no Buscar");    

    return obterLista(cursor);
}
```

### Classe CidadeActivity

```
    package com.example.biowater3;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.example.biowater3.conf.Cidade;
    import com.example.biowater3.data.CidadeDataSource;
    import com.example.biowater3.helper.CidadeAdapter;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class CidadeActivity extends Activity {

        public static final String LOGTAG = "Informacoes";
        CidadeDataSource ds;
        CidadeAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<Cidade> listaCidade;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cidade);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            startDataBase();
            registerForContextMenu ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.cidadeListView));

        }

        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Entramos no OnStart");
            this.popularLista((ArrayList<Cidade>)ds.buscar());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cidade, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_conf) {
               Intent objIntent = new Intent (this, ConfigActivity.class);
               startActivity (objIntent);


            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.setHeaderTitle(listaCidade.get(info.position).getNome());

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ctx_cidade_menu, menu);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.ctx_cidade_menu_editar :
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CadCidadeActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("objCidade", listaCidade.get(info.position) );
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.ctx_cidade_menu_apagar :
                excluirCidade(info.position);
                break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

                    return true;
        }


        private void excluirCidade(int posicaoExcluir) {
            final int posicaoRemover = posicaoExcluir;
            final ArrayList<Cidade> lst = this.listaCidade;

            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setTitle("Excluir - " + lst.get(posicaoExcluir).getNome());
            adb.setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?");
            adb.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Sim", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whitch){
                    if(!(adapter == null)){
                        ds.deletar(lst.get(posicaoRemover));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O Registro: " + lst.get(posicaoRemover) + "Foi Removido Com Sucesso!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        lst.remove(posicaoRemover);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    }
            });

            adb.show();

        }


        private void startDataBase() {
            ds = new CidadeDataSource(this);
            ds.open();                
        }


        private void popularLista (ArrayList<Cidade> cidade){

            this.listaCidade = cidade;
            adapter = new CidadeAdapter(this, this.listaCidade);
            ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cidadeListView);
            lista.setAdapter (adapter);
        }
    }
```

### Classe CidadeDataSource:

```
package com.example.biowater3.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.biowater3.conf.Cidade;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class CidadeDataSource {

    public static final String LOGTAG = "informacoes";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private MainDBBio dbHelper;

    public CidadeDataSource(Context context){

        dbHelper = new MainDBBio (context);

    }

    public void open (){
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "BANCO DE DADOS ABERTO");
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public void close(){
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "BANCO DE DADOS FECHADO");
        dbHelper.close();

    }


public Cidade inserir (Cidade cidade){

        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

        valores.put("nome", cidade.getNome());    
        valores.put("estado", cidade.getEstado());

        cidade.setId(db.insert("cidade", null, valores ));
        return cidade;


    }

public void atualizar (Cidade cidade){

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nome", cidade.getNome());
    valores.put("estado", cidade.getEstado());

    db.update("cidade", valores, "_id = " + cidade.getId(), null );


}

public void deletar (Cidade cidade){

    db.delete("cidade","_id = " + cidade.getId(),null);

}

public  List<Cidade> buscar(){

    String[] colunas = new String [] {"_id", "nome", "estado"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("cidade", colunas, null, null, null, null, "nome ASC");

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Entramos no Buscar");    

    return obterLista(cursor);
}

public List<Cidade> filtrar(String selecao, String ordenacao){

    String[] colunas = new String[] {"_id", "nome"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query("cidade", colunas, selecao , null, null, null , ordenacao);

    return obterLista(cursor);

    }

    private List<Cidade> obterLista (Cursor cursor){

        List<Cidade> listaCidade = new ArrayList<Cidade>();

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0 ){

            while (cursor.moveToNext() ) {

                Cidade cidade = new Cidade();

                cidade.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                cidade.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
                cidade.setEstado(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("estado")));

                listaCidade.add(cidade);
            }
        }

        return listaCidade;
    }



}
```

Comment: Você pensou em fazer uma rotina para verificar se realmente a tabela foi criada nesse banco? Como você sabe que os dados cadastrados estão realmente indo pra tabela que você quer buscar?